# Can you ruin an outlet by touching two wires together.

Tags: power

Recently I was switching the power cord for my dryer and before I attached it to the dryer, I plugged it in to make sure it would fit.  The metals st the other end touched. They popped extremely loud and burnt me. Could I have just ruined my outlet?

Comment: You probably tripped the circuit breaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have ruined your outlet (spark damage) but most likely you caused your circuit breaker to trip.  Frankly, you are probably lucky to be alive (especially if your dryer is a clothes dryer).

Ensure you get someone who knows what s/he is doing to finish the wiring job for you!

Comment: I popped the circuit breaker.  I went and flipped it and everything worked.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You created a dead short in an electrical systems. At a minimum, you have a popped circuit breaker or a burnt fuse. At worst, you have physical damage. Consult a license electrician.